# How to concat Logic App parameter values with expressions in email connector?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I am using Office 365 send email connector to send email to multiple users.
The value of email address is determined from paramter and one of the expression like below :Json View of connector

```
"Send_an_email_3": {
                   "inputs": {
                   "body": {
                    "Body": "Test",
      "Cc": "@concat([parameters('email-address')],';',@{items('For_each_6')?['ChallengedBy']})",           
                      "IsHtml": true,
                                    "Subject": "Test"                                        "To": "[parameters('dtf-email-address')]"
                                  },
```

However, the @concat statment in CC option is not working.

> "Cc":
>   "@concat([parameters('email-address')],';',@{items('For_each_6')?['ChallengedBy']}

Error Message :

> : "The template validation failed: 'The template action
>   'Send_an_email_3' at line '1' and column '130951' is not valid: \"The
>   template language expression
>   '[parameters('email-address')] ; @items('For_each_6')?['ChallengedBy'];' is not
>   valid: the string character ';' at position '36' is not
>   expected.\".'."
>   
>   **Parameter values is determined but expression is unchanged, it should evaluated as it is for subject line.**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by **not wokring** ? You aren't getting the CC mail (or) the logic app itself is throwing the error before executing ?

Comment: while deploying it is throwing error, template is not valid

Comment: Could you show the detail error message or show the logic designer?

Comment: added error message in question.

Comment: @SagarK There is some typo in the expression, Not sure this is the reason there is a **)** bracket missing at last while closing the concat
`@concat([parameters('email-address')],';',@{items('For_each_6')?['ChallengedBy']}) `

Answer (score 1):

According to my test, you could try to use the following code to test.

`"Cc": "@{concat(parameters('email-address'),';',items('For_each_6')?['ChallengedBy'])}"`

Comment: it got deployed as is and not evaluated the parameter value :
 concat(parameters('email-address'),';',items('For_each_6')?['ChallengedBy'])

Comment: You could try to put `parameters('email-address')` into send email `body` to check if it has value in it. I test in my site and could get parameter value.

Comment: @SagarK, any more process? Or could you show me more detail about your designer, so that I could figure out what's wrong with you.

Comment: Updated Question with designer

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to pass an ARM Template parameter `[parameters('email-address')]` to a Logic App Workflow definition language function `@concat()`. Adding ARM Template expressions and functions to be resolved at deployment time in a way that results in Logic Apps expressions and functions to be evaluated at execution time can be messy. Things can become harder when you have string functions in a Logic Apps, like `@concat()` that accept values that are to be obtained from ARM template expressions, like `[parameters()]` or `[variables()]`. At run time, the `@concat()` function expects something like

```
"Cc": "@concat('youremail@domain.com',';',@{items('For_each_6')?['ChallengedBy']}
```

Which is not what you are currently getting using an ARM template parameter.

One way to do it is to avoid using ARM template parameters inside a Logic App workflow definition. I.e., create an Logic App parameter which gets the value from the ARM Template parameter, and then use the Logic App parameter in your `@concat()` function.

You can read the full explanation of how to do this in this post

https://platform.deloitte.com.au/articles/preparing-azure-logic-apps-for-cicd

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Try the following expression in your ARM JSON template,

```
[concat(parameters('email-address')],'';'','@{items(''For_each_6'')?[''ChallengedBy'']}')]
```

It would be more helpful, if you can provide the raw source code of "CC" field.